# Horizontal expand / collapse icons

Tags: icons

I have a webpage with a narrow panel on the left hand side, about 33% of the page width, it contains blocks of text.

At the moment, I have a standard HTML button which expands the panel to fill the screen, and clicking the same button again, collapses it.

I want to swap this button out for a set of expand / collapse icons.

Is there a very commonly used set of horizontal expand / collapse icons?

Comment: Yes, it is known as the burger menu : https://css-tricks.com/three-line-menu-navicon/

Comment: @shash7 that's really more for opening a drop down isn't it?

Comment: Nope, search on google images for sliding menu and you will get the idea

Comment: Just large < and > keyboard symbols.  Optionally with a circle around them.  Or a mathematical angle bracket 〈 〉from unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Arrow-Left / Arrow- Right Icons, which usually indicates the sliding of a section towards the direction, they are pointing.

for e.g.

[image]

[image]